# How do I trigger a subscription error to test recovery on exchange web service

Tags: c#, testing, exchangewebservices

My application uses the EWS API with a Streaming Subscription and everything is working fine and thats a problem for me as i havn't been able to exercise my recovery code for the OnSubscriptionError event.

Here is the code i use to subscribe for streaming notifications

```
private void SetStreamingNotifications(List<FolderId> folder_ids)
{
    streaming_subscriptions_connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(exchange_service, 30);

    streaming_subscriptions_connection.OnDisconnect += OnDisconnect;
    streaming_subscriptions_connection.OnSubscriptionError += OnSubscriptionError;
    streaming_subscriptions_connection.OnNotificationEvent += OnNotificationEvent;

    foreach (var folder_id in folder_ids)
    {
        StreamingSubscription sub = exchange_service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(
            new[] { folder_id },
            EventType.Created,
            EventType.Modified,
            EventType.Deleted,
            EventType.Moved,
            EventType.Copied
        );

        streaming_subscriptions_connection.AddSubscription(sub);
    }

    streaming_subscriptions_connection.Open();
}
```

```
private void OnSubscriptionError(object sender, SubscriptionErrorEventArgs args)
{
    /* What exceptions can i expect to find in "args.Exception" */
    /* Can the streaming subscription be recovered or do i need to create a new one? */
}
```

So my question is how can i trigger a subscription error so i can ensure my code can recover where possible and log / alert when not possible?

**EDIT**
Following a comment from @kat0r i feel i should add:
I'm currently testing against Exchange 2013 and also intend to test against Exchange 2010 SP1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I logged a call with Microsoft to find out if it was possible.  The short answer is no you can't trigger the `OnSubscriptionError` event.

Here are the email responses from MS:

---

In answer to your question, I don’t believe that there is a way you can trigger the OnSubscriptionError event.  The correct action to take if you do encounter this event is to attempt to recreate the subscription that encountered the error.  I will see if I can find out any further information about this, but the event is generated rarely and only when an unexpected error is encountered on the Exchange server (which is why it probably isn’t possible to trigger it).

---

It occurred to me that the EWS Managed API has been open-sourced, and is now available on Github: https://github.com/officedev/ews-managed-api

Based on this, we can see exactly what causes the OnSubscriptionError event to be raised – and as far as I can see, this only occurs in the IssueSubscriptionFailures and IssueGeneralFailure methods, both of which can be found in StreamingSubscriptionConnection.cs.  Any error that is not ServiceError.ErrorMissedNotificationEvents and is tied to a subscription will result in this event being raised (and the subscription being removed).  The error is read from the Response Xml.  Of course, this doesn’t really answer your question of how to trigger the event, as that involves causing Exchange to generate such an error (and I’m afraid there is no information on this).  It may be possible to inject some Xml (indicating an error) into a response in a test environment – in theory, you may be able to use Fiddler to do this (as it allows you to manipulate requests/responses).

Answer (score 0):

A few things you could do is

Throttling will restrict the maximum number of subscriptions you can create so if you just keep creating new subscription you should get a throttling response from the server once you exceed 20.

The other thing is if you take the SubscriptionId and use a different process to unsubscribe you other code should get a Subscription not found.

You also want to test underlying network issue eg break the connection , dns if you have dev environment see what happens when you bounce the Exchange Server etc.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but i haven't been able to trigger the OnSubscriptionError event.  1) I tried to trigger the throttling, i used 79 subscriptions as that was all the accounts i had access to and that didn't trigger the event.  2) I can't figure out how to use the SubscriptionId to unsubscribe from another process using the EWS API.  3) This triggers the OnDisconnect event.

Comment: On another note, if i move the StreamingSubscriptionConnection within the loop creating one for each folder i get the following error after creating 10 StreamingSubscriptionConnection's: You have exceeded the available concurrent connections for your folder.  Try again once your other requests have completed.

Comment: Office365 has a 10 subscription max.

Comment: @kat0r, I didn't know that about Office365.  I'm currently testing against Exchange 2013 and also intend to test against Exchange 2010 SP1.  I'll update my question to include that information, thanks.

Comment: What version you request in ews should not matter, that is a server side throttling setting.